# What is the best way to do per-user-session database connections in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, multiple-databases

I want to connect to db per logged in user. I have one db record per user. After user logged in I use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlserver', mode: 'dblib', host: db.host, port: db.port, username: db.username, password: db.password, database: db.name, timeout: 500000, azure: true)
```

It works all fine. But When I open my application on another machine or browser, It behaves like it is connected to another user db and not to default or current user db. I don't know how to solve this issue. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance